# Long running Mongo queries in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How would one go about updating 1000s of documents in a collection in meteor where forEach has to be used to first calculate the changes for each individual document?

There's a timeout of 10 minutes or so as well as a certain number of megabytes. What I've done in the past is split the updates into groups of 300 and update like that. But is there a simpler way to do it in meteor to allow the for each loop to run for an hour of needed?

Comment: What I have done in the past is to setup a batch job that gets triggered by a cron.  There are a few packages you can use, both Meteor and NPM, that allow you to setup jobs.  In this way, you would simply queue up the work, and have the scheduled job do the work.

Comment: Recommendations for batch mongo packages with meteor?

Comment: There are several on [atmosphere.js](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=cron), and if you are on a later version of Meteor it's easy to pull in an npm package as well.  I think in my project I used percolate:synced-cron, but I was using Meteor 1.2 and npm modules were a little more tricky there. So instead I'd suggest reviewing a few popular options and see what fits what you need.  For what it's worth, I was using this aggregate a bunch of data from one collection to another for reporting, but it should work in many batch instances.

Comment: I'm aware of the cron packages and we have our cron system, but it doesn't help with the batch jobs from what I understand

Comment: Thanks. Got the explanation in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Using [percolate:synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) you could easily do this in batches.

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Update mass quantities',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 1 minute'); // or at any interval you wish
  },
  job: function() {
    var query = { notYetProcessed: true }; // or whatever your criteria are 
    var batchSize = { limit: 300 }; // for example
    myCollection.find(query,batchSize).forEach(doc){
      var update = { $set: { notYetProcessed: false }}; // along with everything else you want to update
      myCollection.update(doc._id,update); 
    }
  }
});
```

This will run every minute until there are no more records to be processed. It will continue running after that of course but won't find anything to update.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason to use synced-cron as opposed to `Meteor.setInterval` in a case like this? If all you're doing is setting an update every minute you might as well use `Meteor.setInterval` (unless you're looking to only do this on one server of many)

Comment: You could also use `setInterval`, I don't see why not. `synced-cron` is nice when you have many cron jobs to manage.